# Is jQuery considered to be outdated?

Tags: jquery

This may be an open and close case but may open some debate. I was speaking with my friend recently who said to me `"jQuery is so 2008"` Now while I don't pretend to know a whole lot about this language (Or JavaScript for that matter), I have used both for projects that I have done in the past. So my question is, is this framework still widely used? Are there newer more "2011" frameworks?

I see that this may be a daft question, as different frameworks have different uses but I have seen a lot of large companies have used jQuery on their site which leads me to believe that of course it has its uses (as does any other language).

What's the general consensus among designers/developers? Is it outdated? Is it still widely used in industry?

EDIT: The reason I ask this is because all the time I've searched for things jQuery related the articles that come up first seem to be dated back a few years...

Another EDIT: Thanks for your points, I think his reason for thinking it was outdated was maybe because the company he worked for didn't use it. Maybe THEY were outdated?!

Comment: "So 2008"? I *hate* your friend on principle. Why don't you ask *him* what *he* uses? And then punch him for me.

Comment: It's not even reached v2. It's got a long time left in it yet. Long live jQuery!

Comment: jQuery is so 2000 and late :P

Comment: The fact that you have put this question out, and thousands of others are going to read it may have started the process already.

Comment: I never understood the obsession that some people have with placing undue emphasis on dates. Like "arrays are 70s". Make a rational argument against something; don't just put a year by it, because the passage of time does **not** necessarily correlate with a decrease in value.

Comment: Oh man, and HTTP is so 1996. Your friend is a trend-bitch :).

Comment: @Kiz: EDIT: Don't search for nonsense "articles" that some nerd has written on his blog that nobody reads. Read the jQuery documentation. It's completely up-to-date.

Comment: I voted to close this, but I'd absolutely _love_ to know what your friend uses.

Comment: I don't think that this question is "subjective and argumentative". Although the OP's friend is a moron, it's a valid question. Technologies *do* come and go, and we can reasonably establish a set of objective criteria for when something is "outdated". melee did a great job of that in his answer.

Comment: @Tomalak I agree with you. There is a clear answer for this question and it's "No. jQuery is not outdated. It's used everywhere, all you need to do is look at the number of questions on this site about it to see that"

Comment: In related news, Stack Overflow runs on jQuery...

Comment: Apologies, didn't mean for this to be confrontational, I just wanted to see if I was right! But as for all your answers, it seems like I was right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your friend is speaking out of total ignorance, and probably just uses whatever was invented within the past 6 months in order to feel "hip" and "cool".

jQuery is still widely used. jQuery is still frequently updated (in fact there was a major release just last month). jQuery is not "outdated".

(In 2008, jQuery was on 1.2.x, which *is* outdated.)

Comment: Agreed. It is one of the few that has both breadth and depth, though of course it's not comprehensive. Perhaps your friend is referring to the relative novelty of frameworks like backbone and spine, or server-side js like node that solve different problems.

Comment: Please add to that that jQuery is de-facto the standard.

Answer (score 7):

Is the development team active?
Is it widely used?
Does it adapt to best practices as they are discovered? Is it bringing new functionality that is making it more valuable to developers?

If you can answer yes to these then there's a good chance it isn't outdated because it is constantly being enhanced.

Your friend sounds like a diva.

Comment: @meagar: Haha yea me too

Comment: @tomalak @meager you've seen them before. You know, when you're at a demo and they ask the most meaningless, offbase questions, like "but how will you support IE11?"

Comment: @melee: "Can I plug my iPhone 4 into it? And does it support Goldman Sachs?" \*stab\*

Comment: @tomalak "I don't think this takes into consideration the organic cross platform virtualized cloud ecosystem"

Comment: @melee: "And, going forward, we will need to leverage that in order to deploy this solution."